# Creating a list of futures

Tags: scala, concurrency

I'm attempting to create a list of futures using the input arguments in the following manner

```
def main( args:Array[String] ){
    val threads = args foreach yield future {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

but every time I try to run it, I get the following error

```
error: ';' expected but 'yield' found.
val threads = args foreach yield future { str =>
```

What do I need to do to my function to make it compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def main( args:Array[String] ){
    val threads = args map future {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

`foreach` doesn't return stuff. `map` returns stuff. They're both methods defined on *iterable collections*.

The `yield` keyword instead is used with the `for` construct (called *for comprehension*) as shown below

```
for (arg <- args) yield future {...whatever}
//in general: for(generator) yield (result for each generated element)
```

*(edit by [pagoda_5b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237450/pagoda-5b), which was rejected but I feel it is worthwhile)*

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def main( args:Array[String] ){
  val threads = for(arg <- args ) yield future{1 + 1} 
}
```